# Dropdown Menu not working on Index.html after adding java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am Creating my personal website but I can not get the drop down to work on desktop then when it is on a mobile devise hide nav and click(using js) to show nav. But its not working only on the Index.html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="header">
            <div class="logo"><a href="assets/img/logo.png" alt="GM">GM</a>
            </div>
        <span class="menu-trigger">Menu</span>
        <nav class="nav clearfix">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-1"></i></a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <li><a href="music.html">Music</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="code.html">Code</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- end of Nav -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/**Header**/
.nav {
    height: 61px;
    background: #381120;
}

.logo a{
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7e7e7e;
    font-size: 43px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

.nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 19px;
}

.nav ul li a {
    color: #7e7e7e;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.nav ul ul.sub-nav {
    display: none;
    background: #381120;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    padding-left: 24px;
}

.nav ul li a.active {
    color: #08a1c7;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #efefef;
}
```

and:

```
.menu-trigger{
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    color: #7e7e7e
}

.menu-trigger p{
    color: #7e7e7e
}

    /**480px**/


@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

    .menu-trigger{
        display: block;
    }

    .nav, .mobile-nav{
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-expanded{
        display: block;
    }

    .nav ul li{
        float: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #7e7e7e;
    }

    .nav ul li:last-child{
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}
```

Here is the JS sorry I forgot to put it on here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {

        jQuery(".nav").slideToggle(400, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: where is the javascript code you mention that conflicts with the index.html?

Comment: just change the function names.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be able to animate all of this with just CSS. You don't even need jQuery for this, other than for the click action maybe.

Also, and this may not be the case, but in past I have had to write my click handlers like this to bypass some odd bugs. SlideToggle in jQuery can cause some glitchy effects and its not really a great way to do animated menu's. Try to avoid slideToggle().

```
$("[your-selector]").on("click",function(){
     /// do something...
});
```

Comment: Well I have Linked the js like this

``<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>``

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/Leyck0n8/) with your code and its seems to work fine. Its rather unclear from what you ask, But what I guess is that your dropdown doesnt work on mobile screen. A problem could be importing jquery in your HTML file. That might solve your problem

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {

        jQuery(".nav").slideToggle(400, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Well I have Linked the js like this

``<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>``

Comment: Well thats a correct way, but the fiddle is working fine meaning a minor mistake might be there, try checking console for any error message

Comment: Nevermind I fix it I added a <div class="content">///content goes here</div> twice causing it to break Thank You for all your help still.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I fix it I added a

```
<div class="content">///content goes here</div>
```

twice causing it to break Thank You for all your help still.